# Login application without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

user can login only by name and email. for this application i need the current user method to use this to update the attributes with other views so please suggest me how to go about this 
for example this is not working

```
def current_user
  @_current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find(session[:current_user_id])
end
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you be more specific and post what you've tried thus far? If you're new to Rails, I suggest the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book); specifically Ch. 9

Comment: Hi thanks for your response i am creating survey application in that there is only one page that user can enter his name and email id then he registration and logged in to the application and start answering the survey so.for authentication without password no gem is there i am trying get the current_user method to use that in questions view but i am unable to get the current user.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more information? The code that's failing, steps you took to fix it, etc. How exactly are you using the `current_user` method?